# Image server tag is not well formed , Error in the Repeater Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I run this part of code ..
Compiler show the error "Parser Error" and show  Image tag in error

```
{
 <Repeater1>
  <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="rptr">
            <table>


                <tr> <th>Catageory <%#Eval("catageory_id") %></th> </tr>
                <tr> <td>Catageory Name</td> <td><%#Eval("c_name") %></td>                    </tr>
                <tr> <td>Image</td> <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%#Eval("c_im_path")%>" Height="100" Width="100"/></td></tr>
                <tr> <td>Color</td> <td><%#Eval("c_color") %></td></tr>
                <tr> <td>Price</td> <td><%#Eval("c_price") %></td></tr>
                <tr> <td>Size</td> <td><%#Eval("c_size") %></td></tr>
                <tr> <td>Description</td> <td><%#Eval("c_description") %></td></tr>

            </table>

        </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</Repeater1>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try if following works

```
<img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "c_im_path")%>'/>
```

I have not tested it perhaps it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You use it like this:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="rptr">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Catageory <%#Eval("catageory_id") %></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Image</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("c_im_path")%>' Height="100" Width="100" /></td>
                    </tr>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

You are missing several attributes in `<Repeater1>` for it to work. And as @CPW already pointed out in his answer, ImageUrl should be used with single quotes for it to work in other server tags.

Also the brackets are not needed.